# Does anyone have information or documentation on the vArea modifier of findViewById()?

Tags: android, layout

I have seen this code segment used in a solution here as to setting background images on layouts in Android:

So in the discussion, a recommendation was made to change:

```
RelativeLayout fondo_area = 
(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.background_areas);
```

To:

```
RelativeLayout fondo_area = 
(RelativeLayout) vArea.findViewById(R.id.background_areas);
```

This seems to be the solution I need, but I cannot seem to find any documentation or information anywhere else regarding this modification, its context, or usage requirements.

Link to Q&A that I discovered this on:

[NullPointerException when draw background RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626573/nullpointerexception-when-draw-background-relativelayout)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: final View vArea = li_area.inflate(R.layout.areas_detalles_cpa, null);
the vArea you are talking about is a view 
you can put your code so that we can help further

Comment: A little more info - vArea in that code snippet is not a modifier, it's a variable.  Based on this misunderstand (or just incorrect terminology) and some other details of your question it sounds like you could use some beginning Java knowledge to help communicate about your code with others.  I'd recommend going through a beginner Java and/or Android tutorial or lesson.

Comment: @nasch, I have been coding for a couple of years, primarily in Java and Script haha. I will admit to not having much beyond the basics in formal knowledge so the terminology may be a bit off, but I do not see how it could be a variable in this circumstance. It is something of a modification to the findViewById() call that I cannot interpret properly.

As for the code sampling, I am really just asking for clarification on the linked Q&A, as I am new here and cannot comment on that thread, and having a separate one will help others wondering what vArea is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely a variable.

`final View vArea = li_area.inflate(R.layout.areas_detalles_cpa, null);`

`final` indicates the value cannot be changed.  `View` indicates the type of the variable.  `vArea` is the name of the variable.  Then everything on the right of the = is an expression, whose value is assigned to `vArea`.  If this doesn't seem right to you, I again encourage you to go back and hit some basic Java training, because you may have missed something the first time around.  Perhaps it is nothing more than using some terminology incorrectly.  If it helps, I have been developing in Java for about 20 years.  I say that not to brag or put you down, but just to give some perspective on my level of experience and assure you that I'm coming from a position of some knowledge on the subject.

As to the reason why the change you mention fixes your problem.  I can't be certain because I don't know exactly what the problem is and haven't seen all the relevant code, but here's my guess.

`RelativeLayout fondo_area = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.background_areas);`

This gives you an error that `findViewbyId` is not defined (or cannot be resolved, or whatever the wording is).  That is because that code is from an Activity, which has that method defined, and you pasted it into a Fragment, which does not.

`RelativeLayout fondo_area = (RelativeLayout) vArea.findViewById(R.id.background_areas);`

Now it works because you're calling `findviewById` on a `View`, where that method is defined.  Does that sound like a plausible explanation?

On a minor side note, you may be able to remove the cast to RelativeLayout.  With one of the recent Android updates that is no longer necessary.  It might be a matter of targeting Java 7 or higher, I don't remember for sure.

Comment: You are totally right! I think the major problem is that I have been on and off dabbling in code for a while, now I am taking it more seriously and did not realize where I was at. Thank you for your patience. Also, the explanation is not far off. But I am reworking the code now that I have a better understanding of it anyways. And as far as the cast, I will check for an update and see! Thank you again.